# Como insertar los datos en slqlite desde python, flask, html?

Tags: html, python, base-de-datos, flask

Hola tengo problemas con mi codigo estoy hice una aplicacion para registrar un nombre , correo y numero pero cuando inserto los datos en html  no aparecen en la base de dato, he revisado en varios foros y la coneccion esta bien no se que peda ser si alguien sabe mas del tema me vendria bien su ayuda.

Este es mi codigo para insertar en py

```
app = Flask(__name__)

conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
print("**DateBase Is Connect**")



@app.route('/addrec', methods =['POST','GET'])
def addrec():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      try: 
          nombre = request.form['nombre']
          email = request.form['email']
          phone_number = request.form['phone_number']

          with slq.connect('user.db') as conn:
               cur = conn.cursor()
               cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (nombre,email,phone_number) VALUES (?,?,?)",(nombre,email,phone_number) )

               conn.Commit()
               msg = "Record successfylly operation"

      except:
            conn.rollback()
            msg = "error in insert operation"

      finally: 
              return render_template('result.html')
              conn.close()
```

y mi html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %} 
<div class="container">
 <form action = "{{ url_for('addrec') }}" method = "POST">
    <h2>Sign Up </h2>
    Name<br>
    <input type="text" name ="nombre"/></br>

    E-mail<br>
    <input type="text" name="email"/></br>

    Phone Number<br>
    <input type="number" name="phone_number"/></br>

    <input type="submit" value="submit"/></br>

    </form>


     </div>


{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos te sugiero realizar de la siguiente forma:

```
from flask import g
import sqlite3

....
..
g.db = sqlite3.connect("miBase.db")
...
@app.route('/addrec', methods = ['POST'])
def signup():
    nombre = request.form['nombre']
    g.db.execute("INSERT INTO tabla VALUES (?)", [nombre])
    g.db.commit()
    return redirect('/')
```

Para multiples parametros a insertar será:

```
g.db.execute("INSERT INTO tabla VALUES (?,?,?)", [param1, param2,param3])
```

Espero te sirva y suerte.

Referencia: [flask database](http://opentechschool.github.io/python-flask/extras/databases.html)